# Passing System.Drawing.Common.Bitmap (.NET Standard 2.0) to class expecting System.Dwawing.Bitmap (.NET 4.7.2)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I am wokring on converting some class libraries from .NET 4.7.2 over to .NET Standard (so that other Standard/Core assemblies can better use them), and I'm running into a problem with a particular third party library. This library performs image processing, and many of it's classes' methods take `Image` or `Bitmap` objects from the classic `System.Drawing` namespace.

I have found the .NET Standard package `System.Drawing.Common` that has the compatibility classes in it, so that my own uses of those classes in my source code is working fine. But when I try to pass one of these classes into this library, I get an error:

> Reference to type 'Bitmap' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

I think I understand what's going on here (the types are defined in assemblies with different names, so they are different types). But is there any way to make these work as-is? Or will it require the vendor of the third-party library to make changes on their side to support .NET Standard?

Comment: Do you know Windows compatibility pack? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was able to call the methods using the dark magic of reflection. I didn't believe it would work, but it did (at least it seems to):

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ImageElement));
var elem = (ImageElement)assembly.CreateInstance("Winnovative.ImageElement", true, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] { 0f, 0f, 1f, 1f, bmp }, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Drawing` is not part of .NET Standard so the types are not compatible.

Additionally, I wouldn't use `System.Drawing.Common` as it's just a wrapper around GDI+ which doesn't work well in multi-threaded environments like server side code.

I would recommend moving to [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) or [SkiaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp), both of which should work in all of your projects.

Comment: How will moving to ImageSharp allow me to pass parameters into an existing third-party library that expects a System.Drawing.Bitmap? If that can be made to work it would be perfect but I'm skeptical...

Comment: I meant you would be have to update the system that expects the bitmap too.

Comment: oh, got it. I have no control over that and find it unlikely :\. I've begun looking for a replacement library in case the vendor is unresponsive.

Comment: You may be able to use the compatability pack then. Of course that means losing cross platform and I'm not sure System.Drawing is part of it yet.

Comment: System.Drawing.Common is a cross-platform part of NET Core. It works on Linux and macOS. You'll need to install libgdiplus on your machine - make sure you use a recent version.

Comment: @FrederikCarlier Yes, but it's still a huge problem to use it on Windows in a multithreaded environment, such as ASP.NET Core, that is why I would stay well away from it. But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @FrederikCarlier See [here](https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet) for a good write up.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the link, I know about System.Drawing's limitations. The downvote was because of the argument (admittedly in the comments) System.Drawing.Common is not cross-platform (it is).

Comment: @FrederikCarlier You can't vote based on comments, that makes no sense. Also, I never said it wasn't cross-plat.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm, perhaps I misinterpreted "You may be able to use the compatability pack then. Of course that means losing cross platform and I'm not sure System.Drawing is part of it yet"?

Comment: @FrederikCarlier Yes, the compat pack is Windows specific.

Comment: @DavidG That's not quite correct. Not everything in in the compat pack is Windows specific. See the table in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/, about half of it is cross-platform, the other half is Windows only.